# Problem to get report from SQL Server timer

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, timezone, hosting

One of the questions we get all the time is how to change server time so it matches the time zone of the customer or users. Unfortunately, the answer is — you can’t. The web server can only run in one time zone, so the time is going to be “off” in the other 39 time zones.

What you can do to work around this is convert the server time to your local time. .NET makes this easy with a built-in TimeZoneInfo class that can be used to convert one time zone to another.

Then my server time would be 12.30 hours different from my local time, i.e. subtract 12 hours and 30 minutes from my local time to get my server time. I need to get my local time from the server time. How can it be achieved?

I try to have a class:

```
protected DateTime GetCurrentTime()
{
        DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime _localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(serverTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Arab Standard Time");
        return _localTime;
}
```

And this is how to get the TimeZoneId on the server:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       foreach (TimeZoneInfo zoneID in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
        {
            Response.Write(zoneID.Id + "<br/>");
        }
}
```

But I don't know what is wrong I do or what the good why to do that. All I have is a database on the server and connected with c# windows application, and I try this code to get my today report `> DATEADD(d, - 1, GETDATE())` but it work after 11:30 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't write code that cares about what the server's time zone is.  Instead, write code that works with the UTC time and a specific time zone.

Your C# code should be like this:

```
DateTime dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Arab Standard Time");
```

For SQL, generally you should be recording UTC-based values, in which case there's no conversion needed at all.  However, if you need to convert because you're storing local value then you can use the system's current UTC time and the [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql) function like this:

```
WHERE dt > (DATEADD(d, -1, GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Arab Standard Time')
```

In both cases, preferably the time zone identifier `'Arab Standard Time'` is coming from a variable, rather than being hardcoded.

Comment: the frist code is working good for me but the second one i  not working in the sql server

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a difference between the SQL server system's local time zone and the time zone used for time stamping recorded data. I'd suggest to inspect the latest recorded data and compare that to the SQL server system's local time; that should reveal such a difference.

If the recorded data is time stamped in UTC, for example, then you could retrieve the last 24 hours worth of data for a time range between DATEADD(d, -1, GETUTCDATE()) and GETUTCDATE(). Note that this does not necessarily give you a midnight-to-midnight report for local time; for that you have to first calculate the UTC time range from the local midnight-to-midnight time and then query for the calculated UTC time range.

Comment: relly i know this is the best way to do that bout im new in coding and i think it is hard for me now to calculate it and do it in the write way